# Why does my PRIME1 - SPOJ implementation gets SIGSEGV, even though it runs fine for all test cases in my pc?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

Input:

> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Here's the link to the problem : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Here is my program:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
 int n,m,t,i=0,j,k=0;
 int tm[10],tn[10];
 scanf("%d",&t); //test cases
 while(i<t)
 {
  scanf("%d %d", &tm[i],&tn[i]);
  i++;
 } 
 int * a = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));

 while(k<t)
    {
     n=tn[k];
     m=tm[k];
     a[0]=a[1]=0;
     for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=i;
     for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
     {
        if(a[i])
        {
            for(j=(i*i);j<=n;j+=i)
            {
            a[j]=0;
            }
        }
     } 
     for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
     {
        if(a[i])
            printf("%d \n", a[i]);
     }
     k++;
     printf("\n");
    }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's a bit unreasonable to ask a question that's basically "Please debug my code". But you might want to look at your malloc call. How is `n` determined in your code? Do you know that `a` is not null? What would happen if the memory allocation failed?

Comment: Always compile your code with warnings. That would have prevented the bug that Rupert hints at

Comment: @user3298129 In different coding site u can declare array of size till 10^6  . So if n=10^9 you will get SIGSEV error . You have to change the logic of your code...

Answer (score 0):

Declaring an array of size 10^9 is not permitted on many coding sites.That might be causing SIGSEGV.

Any way you need to change logic of your code since even if you resolve this error , your logic will possibly give you TLE